# Validating User Input While Typing using RegEx

Tags: regex, validation, decimal, user-input, negative-number

I am struggling to write the RegEx for the following criteria:

- The number can be positive / negative
- Optional - at the start
- Between 1 and 5 numbers before the decimal point
- 2 decimal places only (optional)
- Stop user from typing more than 1 . or -

This is the regex I have tried to implement which does not work for me.

```
^((-?[0-9]{1,5}(\.?){1,1}[0-9]{0,2})
```

It should allow the user to type out the following numbers.

```
-1.12
12345
1
123
12.12
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is there any reason you have to do all these checks in ONE regex?

Comment: Maybe `^-?\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$` will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hello Wiktor, this works for positive numbers but it's not allowing me to type negative numbers, I have to type the positive number out first then add the minus symbol at the start afterwards. When deleting the number after I have added the minus symbol it deletes the first number and the minus symbol at the same time - do you know why this is?

Comment: Then try `^-?\d{0,5}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi this is great thanks! Only thing I have noticed is that I am still able to type -. but I assume there is no way for me to get around this as it would stop the user from typing - at all

Comment: Yes, or use `^-?\d{0,5}(?:(?<=\d)\.\d{0,2})?$` if lookbehinds are allowed. Can you use lookbehinds?

Comment: @Oliver I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60615000/3832970), please consider accepting and upvoting all the answers that proved helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^-?\d{0,5}(?:(?<=\d)\.\d{0,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/47dUzn/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `\d{0,5}` - zero to five digits
- `(?:(?<=\d)\.\d{0,2})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `(?<=\d)` - there must be a digit immediately to the left of the current location
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{0,2}` - zero, one or two digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I don't get why a lookbehind would work and this does not... `^-?(?:\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{0,2})?)?$` It gives the same matches https://regex101.com/r/NGztte/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Sorry, I can't quite test them all now. I believe you are right and the regexps are equivalent, but I have seen so many scenarios and we are still unaware of what software OP uses. So, I just rely on OP feedback in such cases.

Comment: I was just curious that maybe I missed something. All is well :-)

Answer (score 1):

The regex `^(-?(\d{1,5}(\.\d{0,2})?)?)$` should work if you want to match strings that end in `.` such as `123.` [demo of this regex](https://regex101.com/r/lhIanT/1)

Otherwise, change the `0` to a `1` as follows: `^(-?(\d{1,5}(\.\d{1,2})?)?)$`. Then it will only match strings that have a digit after the decimal point.

The regex that you posted allows strings with more than 2 digits after the decimal point because it stops matching after the 2 digits, even if the string continues. Adding a `$` at the end of the regex stops it from matching strings that continue after the part we want.

This regex `^(-?\d{1,5}(\.\d{0,2})?)$` will validate the input once the user has finished typing, because I assume that you don't want `-`to be valid at that point.

Comment: Hello, please see my comment on original question!

Comment: @Oliver I updated my answer. This new regex should do the job. Keep in mind that you probably don't want to accept `-` as a valid input once the user has finished typing, so you would have to validate it with another regex

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate while typing, you could make use of optional groups to accept intermediate values and do a final check on the whole pattern when processing the value.

```
^-?(?:\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{0,2})?)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `-?` Optional hyphen
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d{1,5}` Match 1-45 digits
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\.\d{0,2}` Match a dot and 0-2 digits
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NGztte/1)

To validate the final pattern, you could match an optional `-`, 1-5 digits and an optional decimal part:

```
^-?\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pr9Dze/1)

Comment: Hi, please see my comment on original question!

Comment: @Oliver Is it not working? You can type all the chars right?

Comment: It would not allow me to type - at the start of the string!

Comment: @Oliver This would allow you to type a `-` at the start of the string https://regex101.com/r/NGztte/1 The first link was not correct, I have updated it.